# Mongo DB aggregate query in php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I am new in MongoDB so facing issue in making join query in mongo please help
I have two collection "user" and "user_login_details"

Previously I have below query to fetch record from single collection

```
$data = $this->mongodb->select()->where(array('instituteId' => $instituteId))->where_not_in('type', array($instituteAdmin))->get('user');
```

Now I want to fetch records from two collection "user" have single row and for that row multiple entries of login detail present in "user_login_details" collection.

I try with aggregate as below

```
db.user.aggregate([
{$match: { instituteId: '5954ee6dcf2169d50d51b88d'} },
{
 $lookup:
   {
     from: "user_login_details",
     localField: "_id",
     foreignField: "user_id",
     as: "user_login_details"
   }
}
]).pretty()
```

But need one more condition as per my first query in php

```
->where_not_in('type', array($instituteAdmin))
```

How I can add this in aggregate query.

Also above query will return data with multiple login details as below.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5954ee6dcf2169d50d51b88e"),
"email" : "abc@gmail.com",
"instituteId": "5954ee6dcf2169d50d51b88d",
"type": "Institute Admin"
"user_name" : "SA-011",
"religion" : "",
"caste" : "",
"bloodGroup" : "",
"groups" : "",
"reset_password" : NumberLong(1),
"aws_arn" : "",
"user_login_details" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b069955df05aeda0f8b4568"),
        "user_id" : ObjectId("5954ee6dcf2169d50d51b88e"),
        "ip" : "::1",
        "my_session_id" : "3199d6fd6ecfef1ec63bc1760115d116",
        "login_time" : ISODate("2018-05-24T10:52:05Z"),
        "logout_time" : ISODate("2018-05-24T11:04:47Z")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b069c52df05ae6e358b4567"),
        "user_id" : ObjectId("5954ee6dcf2169d50d51b88e"),
        "ip" : "::1",
        "my_session_id" : "b2d33ea8bc7cc3bb8090fc1dd15f7371",
        "login_time" : ISODate("2018-05-24T11:04:50Z"),
        "logout_time" : ""
    }
]
}
```

I need only latest record from "user_login_details" collection.

Please help by creating query in PHP as I used "CodeIgniter MongoDB Active Record Library".

Thanks in advance.